# Register micro-services using spring-eureka from more than 1 server

Tags: spring-cloud

I have a set of micro-services which need to communicate to each other.

The total number of micro-services does not fit to single physical server so I need to spread them out among 2 different servers.

My idea (do not know if correct) is to have spring-eureka instance per server to which all services from this particular server register. So:

- Services (A,B) register to Eureka on Server 1.
- Services (C,D) register to Eureka on Server 2.

After that eureka instances will exchange their knowledge ([Peer Awareness](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR4/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html)).

[image]

The questions are:

1. Does described idea is correct approach? Or rather there should exist just single Eureka instance on single server to which all services from both servers will register (i.e. Eureka exists only on Server1)?
2. If described idea is correct then as I understand ports 8761 should be opened on Server1 and Server2 to allow communication between "Eurekas"? And the configuration should be as following:

   - Eureka on Server 1:
     `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http[s]://server2address:8761/eureka/`
   - Eureka on Server 2:
     `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http[s]://server1address:8761/eureka/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) normally you would have a server for each service (A,B,C,D eureka1 and eureka2)

2) eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone is a comma separated list so it is more like "eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http[s]://server1address:8761/eureka/,http[s]://server2address:8761/eureka/" for each service

Hope that helps, cheers

Comment: p.s. I assume that you don't have only 2 servers for 6 services ;)

Comment: It is the test environment. In fact we can simplify case that:

Server1 has Service A and
Server2 has Service B

But I need to place Eureka somewhere. As I understand for now I should just choose one of the servers and all services from both servers should subscribe to this single Eureka?

(On prod env it will be on its own server ;])

Comment: Eureka should be placed on a Server3 but technically it makes no difference where eureka is located. You can easily place it on Server1 for example. Every service will register itself on the eureka instance (if configured correctly). If you have multiple eureka instances the will recognize each other and should start to replicate their data (same configuration like every other service)